# TIMESTAMPDIFF IN RELATIONAL ALGEBRA

Tags: database, relational-algebra

Can anybody guide me as to how I can represent TIMESTAMPDIFF function in relational algebra? Would that be simple as we use sum ,avg and other functions?

Answer (score 0):

Standard relational algebra doesn't have domain-specific operators. However, nothing prevents you from defining your own. Provided you declare and use it properly, I see no problem with something like:

ρ<sub>interval/TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, a, b)</sub>(π<sub>TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, a, b)</sub>(σ<sub>a = 2017/03/09</sub>(R)))

A better option may be to define TIMESTAMPDIFF as a relation with header (Interval, Date1, Date2, Amount), then use the usual relational operators to select the interval and dates you want, and project the Amount.